# MySQL: I have some problems with primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I'm deleting a person with their metadatas from a db, the database counts the ID + 1 if I add someone new to the database which is normally the right and the safe way, right?

So when I'm deleting the person with the meta_id (primary key) 10, can the next added person get the meta_id 10 again?

Comment: No, if you have a primary key of 10, and you are using 'auto_increment' in MySQL, then deleting this row won't free up the primary key of 10. The next one will be 11 regardless of whether the '10 slot' is free.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, MySQL will keep an internal index iterator that increments regardless of the data you delete from the database. Therefore, if you create a new row with primary key ID of 10, and then you delete that row and create a new one, the primary key ID of the new row will be 11 if you rely on auto_increment for the iteration of your ID. This behavior is expected.

In simpler terms, no. MySQL's auto_increment will not allow what you describe.

Comment: Please tell me if this explanation is difficult to understand, and I will try to explain it better. Your English is okay. :)

Comment: If this answer suits you, please don't forget to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers posted so far, bear in mind that primary key of the database has only one purpose - to identify a row. It's not there to make it easy to use sequential numbering. There are many implications when you want to achieve the functionality you described - you'd disturb the internals of MySQL (to be more precise, of InnoDB engine) when it comes to writing data to hard disk, making it slower in turn.

If you need to have some sort of sequential numbering related to your records, you either create triggers to deal with that or you use some sort of numbering method while displaying the records from database. You don't use primary key or auto_increment for that purpose.